# iOS - How to set width of TableView in TableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift3

using a TableViewController, how can I resize the length of the cells within it?

[image]

> As you can see, the length of the cells is extended to the entire
>   display. How can I reduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

Chanage the frame in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

or change in

> Called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout
>   its subviews.When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews.

So instead of doing it in view will appear,over ride the **willLayoutSubviews**:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

      self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

}
```

or efficient way

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:YES]
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 200)];
}
```

**swift3**

Change the frame in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(200), height: CGFloat(200))
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

or change in

> Called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout
>   its subviews.When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews.

So instead of doing it in view will appear,over ride the **willLayoutSubviews**:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(200), height: CGFloat(200))
}
```

or efficient way

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(true)
self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), width: CGFloat(200), height: CGFloat(200))
}
```

Comment: humm..in swift: 'override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    }' ?

Comment: i adapted viewDidAppear in swift3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES]
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
}
```